# localhost/wordpress(or other application), how does it work?

Tags: server, apache, xampp

Just a quick question I can't seem to find the answer to. Maybe I just can't formulate the right question or the right keywords.

How does xampp identify which web application to open if the url is presented as localhost/wordpress or localhost/notwordpress? I assume it's the wp_option table that drives this, but how about other applications which does not have wp_option?

I am using

XAMPP

Bitnami

Wordpress.org

all in local machine

Comment: The _A_ in XAMPP stands for Apache, this is your webserver. And here it will be decided, where to route your request to. Usually you have a rule for _localhost_ in there that will point to a location, _/wordpress_ is just a folder inside it

Comment: when you use XAMPP, you put your projects inside *htdocs* folder, which acts as the your server's root. **localhost** or 127.0.0.1 usually points to your own root folder, in this case folder named htdocs, since your server handler is Apache. In this example, it has nothing to do with what cms or what project you have, Apache handles *htdocs* folder as root and if there're any subfolders inside it, you can access them by either http://localhost/yoour_project_folder or can replace localhost with 127.0.0.1